# Error message in online Rails course on URL Shortener

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

[TryBloc](http://www.trybloc.com) has an online course that teaches Rails among other programming languages. There's a [course on URL Shortening](http://www.trybloc.com/courses/url_shortener), and I'm a bit puzzled by the rspec test that is failing on the fourth lesson (Storing the short codes).

This is supposed to be something simple, and each lesson builds upon the previous ones. I feel as though I'm overlooking something small, but can't spot it. The error from rspec isn't helping either. How can I fix this and pass this fourth lesson? Am I reading the instruction correctly?

The instruction:

> In your first challenge, we asked you to return only a random string of 5 digits.
>
> CHALLENGE Set the code you generate as a key in Redis so that we remember the same key for a domain.

The example given:

```
REDIS.set("12345", "google.com")
REDIS.get("12345") # google.com
REDIS.exists("12345") # true, the key exists
```

The Code that can be modified:

```
require 'sinatra'

configure do
  require 'redis'
  require 'uri'
  REDISTOGO_URL = ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"]
  uri = URI.parse(REDISTOGO_URL)
  REDIS = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)
end

get "/" do
  "Try going to /shorten?url=http://www.google.com"
end

# yourapp.com/?url=http://google.com
get "/shorten" do
  # Write your code below to create a random number.
  random_number = (1..9).to_a.shuffle.sample(5).join("")

  REDIS.set(random_number, params[:url])
end

# Please leave this extra space at the bottom
```

The error:

> F..
>
> Failures:
>
> 1) URL Shortener returns a short code
>
> ```
> Failure/Error: last_response.body.should =~ /(\d){5}/
>
>   expected: /(\d){5}/
>
>        got: "http://google.com" (using =~)
>
>   Diff:
>
>   @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
>
>   -/(\d){5}/
>
>   +http://google.com
>
> # ./spec:42:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
> ```
>
> Finished in 0.4169 seconds
>
> 3 examples, 1 failure
>
> Failed examples:
>
> rspec ./spec:40 # URL Shortener returns a short code

Comment: It's difficult for me to say which, if any, of your methods is failing the spec. However, this much is clear: the spec is testing a piece of your code, and expecting it to return a 5-digit code. Your code, however, is returning `"http://google.com"`. As an experiment, you might try putting `"12345"` as the last line in your `get "/shorten"` block.

Comment: Doing that, I get: response_1.body.should_not == response_2.body
       expected not: == "12345"
                got:    "12345".

Comment: That is because the RSpec is trying to ensure that the `"/shorten"` route does not return the same value between requests. I guess REDIS' job is to ensure that codes are not re-used? I'm going to post a suggested solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the RSpec is expecting `"/shorten"` to return a 5-digit code, which does not repeat between requests.

```
# yourapp.com/?url=http://google.com
get "/shorten" do
  # Write your code below to create a random number.
  random_number = (1..9).to_a.shuffle.sample(5).join("")

  # make sure that we don't re-use any numbers
  while REDIS.exists(random_number)
     random_number = (1..9).to_a.shuffle.sample(5).join("")
  end

  REDIS.set(random_number, params[:url])

  # return the number
  random_number
end
```

Comment: +1 Saw this and just ended my block with randome_number, thus returning and the test passed. That was all that was missing it seems. But this also solves step 5 of the lesson. Thanks!